# Easyjet flight change

Tags: air-travel, luggage, easyjet

If on my original flight I had booked and paid for a seat and hold baggage, when I change this flight to a later date will the extras like hold baggage get transferred across to the new flight booking or do I lose them?

Comment: What do the EasyJet booking terms & conditions say?

Comment: They don't say which is why I am asking.

Answer (score 13):

I have now continued to change my flight with Easyjet and it did move over both my extra legroom seats and baggage that I had prebooked on the previous flight.